# Redirect on login page after log out on browser's back button on-click

Tags: java, authentication, wicket, logout

Any good website like any one of the various services provided by [google](http://www.google.com) has a feature that on browser's back button on click it will redirect you to the login page again. I think [google](http://www.google.com) use some thing like [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) (maybe I am wrong, at this moment this is not what I want to know)!

How can we detect that button's on click and redirect user again to login page? Is there any configuration needed in [org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html) or we can detect it from the MyLoginPage which extends [org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to deal with cacheability of your pages. In my application, the cache for pages is set to none, and any action of back button cause the browser to check the server for changes.

Comment: @Tapas In `WebPage#setHeaders(WebResponse response)` default behavior is to put "pragma:no-cache" and it seems to work well for me. Please make sure you didn't overriden it removing the default behavior.